# remove white space before comma

Tags: jquery, html, regex

I have following output from DB:

```
<span data-title="Score">Score: 6-3 , 6-4</span>
```

I have extra space before comma that I need to get rid off.
I am using jQuery to achieve this since I don't have access to DB myself.
If anybody can provide me with proper RegEx it would save me some time.

Thank you

Comment: Did you tried anything? We are here to help, but you need to help yourself  first

Comment: without regex no ? str.replace(" , " , ",");

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use:

```
$('[data-title="Score"]').text().replace(/ \,/g, ','); //or .replace(" ,", ','); for single occurence
```

if you want to replace the text :

```
$('[data-title="Score"]').text(function( index,text ) {
  return text.replace(/ \,/g, ','); //or .replace(" ,", ','); for single occurence
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1j80dh15/)**

Comment: awesome!! i needed multiple occurence so thanks for pointing that out as well.

Comment: this $('[data-title="Score"]').text().replace(/ \,/g, ','); does not seem to work for me. The second one does but i have <br> or HTML in the div and it seems to remove that as well. Any way to not remove my other HTML in the div?

Comment: @Aaron: there are no whitespaces before comma, there are letters. let me guess. do you want to remove those `br` elements that gives line breaks??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace()` function:

```
$('[data-title="Score"]').text().replace(' ,', ',');
```

You can find more about `replace` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(function(){
var textWithoutcomma = $('span').text().replace(' ,',',');
console.log(textWithoutcomma);
});
```